# How to create wavy weave lines pattern in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, photoshop-effects, filter

I am trying to duplicate the following image in Photoshop of weaved, wavy lines so I can make it higher resolution or vector but I'm not having any luck getting the pattern right. I have managed to get wavy lines, but they are uniform and don't really have the "fabric" or "flag" look that this image has.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: example image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you have Adobe Illustrator, you can do the following.

1. Create a grid using the **Rectangular Grid** tool.
   [image]
2. Make a gradient mesh. Go to **Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh** and select the number grid lines of lines you want to distort with.

[image]

3. Use the direct select tool and grab the handle of the mesh to distort the grid.
   [image]

Comment: +1 Great answer, but I think you should let them know to do this in Illustrator to avoid confusion since the question is about Photoshop.